# Export DSL from MagicDraw

Tags: uml, dsl, magic-draw

I made an UML profile (with stereotypes) in MagicDraw. I also made a special diagram type for my profile as well as some new buttons.

[image]

But when I open my project on another PC, everything is gone - I can't see my diagram or my buttons any more.

**How can I export/save my DSL settings?**

Answer (score 0):

On their website MagicDraw UML states that models generated in ver 1.7 of java might have issues with working on java 1.6.

I think this is true for the latest ver of MagicDraw UML.

Maybe your first PC is running 1.7 and the other 1.6.